# ImportError: cannot import name 'network' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Getting this error when trying to import tf_agents.environments running on Tensorflow 2.3.0, using anaconda environment. Have tried to reinstall tensorflow, still getting same error. Running the jupyter notebook in as admin, still getting same error. I am using python 3.8

```
from tf_agents.environments import suite_gym



ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b9cd8ac2787f> in <module>
----> 1 from tf_agents.environments import suite_gym
      2 
      3 # env = suite_gym.load("Breakout-v4")
      4 # env

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\__init__.py in <module>
     24 from tf_agents.environments import tf_py_environment
     25 from tf_agents.environments import trajectory_replay
---> 26 from tf_agents.environments import utils
     27 from tf_agents.environments import wrappers

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\utils.py in <module>
     23 from tf_agents.environments import tf_environment
     24 from tf_agents.environments import tf_py_environment
---> 25 from tf_agents.policies import random_py_policy
     26 from tf_agents.specs import array_spec
     27 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\policies\__init__.py in <module>
     16 """Policies Module."""
     17 
---> 18 from tf_agents.policies import actor_policy
     19 from tf_agents.policies import boltzmann_policy
     20 from tf_agents.policies import epsilon_greedy_policy

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\policies\actor_policy.py in <module>
     27 import tensorflow_probability as tfp
     28 
---> 29 from tf_agents.networks import network
     30 from tf_agents.policies import tf_policy
     31 from tf_agents.specs import tensor_spec

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\networks\__init__.py in <module>
     16 """Networks Module."""
     17 
---> 18 from tf_agents.networks import actor_distribution_network
     19 from tf_agents.networks import actor_distribution_rnn_network
     20 from tf_agents.networks import bias_layer

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\networks\actor_distribution_network.py in <module>
     24 import tensorflow as tf  # pylint: disable=g-explicit-tensorflow-version-import
     25 
---> 26 from tf_agents.networks import categorical_projection_network
     27 from tf_agents.networks import encoding_network
     28 from tf_agents.networks import network

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\networks\categorical_projection_network.py in <module>
     24 import tensorflow_probability as tfp
     25 
---> 26 from tf_agents.networks import network
     27 from tf_agents.networks import utils
     28 from tf_agents.specs import distribution_spec

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tf_agents\networks\network.py in <module>
     31 
     32 # pylint:disable=g-direct-tensorflow-import
---> 33 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import network as keras_network  # TF internal
     34 from tensorflow.python.training.tracking import base  # TF internal
     35 from tensorflow.python.util import tf_decorator  # TF internal

ImportError: cannot import name 'network' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine' (C:\Users\Vision\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does it work with TF 2.2?

Comment: When I run using TF 2.2 it says I have to upgrade to TF 2.3

Comment: Then you might want to ask this as an issue on the tf_agents Github, from the traceback it looks like an internal problem and nothing you can easily fix yourself

Comment: I just had a similar issue. TF 2.3 requirement comes from tensorflow_probability 0.11.0 which was released some hours ago. I resolved this for now by specifying versions tensorflow>=2.2,<2.3 and tensorflow_probability<0.11,>=0.10

Answer (score 4):

Am a bit late here, but faced a similar issue.

How I resolved the issue :

Uninstall the current version of `tf_agents`, use

`pip uninstall tf-agents`

Please  install the current `tf-agents-nightly` (0.6.0) [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents).

use `pip install tf-agents-nightly`

`from tf_agents.environments import suite_gym`