# Cannot import name 'network' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

When trying to load BERT QA I get the following ImportError:
"Cannot import name 'network' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine'"
The full error log follows below

Following this post,
[ImportError: cannot import name 'network' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152966/importerror-cannot-import-name-network-from-tensorflow-python-keras-engine)

I have tried the following steps,

```
pip uninstall tf-agents
pip install tf-agents-nightly
```

and then in Python,

```
from tf_agents.environments import suite_gym
```

However, this did not resolve the problem. Any suggestions would be very welcome!

In case it is helpful, I'm running TensorFlow version 2.3.0. Also, the script **init**.py referred to below does exist, however the file is empty, i.e. 0 bytes.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-323bac0cb5ba> in <module>
----> 1 from bert_qa import squad

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bert_qa/squad.py in <module>
     34 from . import model_training_utils
     35 from . import bert_modeling as modeling
---> 36 from . import bert_models
     37 from . import optimization
     38 from . import input_pipeline

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bert_qa/bert_models.py in <module>
     25 from . import bert_modeling
     26 from . import weighted_sparse_categorical_crossentropy
---> 27 from . transformer_encoder import TransformerEncoder
     28 from . albert_transformer_encoder import AlbertTransformerEncoder
     29 from . import bert_classifier

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bert_qa/transformer_encoder.py in <module>
     22 import tensorflow as tf
     23 
---> 24 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import network  # pylint: disable=g-direct-tensorflow-import
     25 
     26 from . import activations

ImportError: cannot import name 'network' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine' (/home/user810643/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install tf-agents 0.6.0 version for Tebsorflow 2.3.

```
pip install tf-agents==0.6.0
```

Looks like the issue was caused due to TF-Agents and Tensorflow version incompatibility. For more information, please take a look at this [release](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents#releases) notes. Thanks!